# MP4 pseudo-streaming not working in JWPlayer Flash mode

Tags: nginx, html5-audio, jwplayer, pseudo-streaming

I've configured a NginX with `mod_mp4` to stream mp4 medias and I'm using JWPlayer 5 in both HTML5 and Flash modes.

Now seeking feature works in webkit browsers which support mp4 playback but in Firefox and other browsers which JWPlayer uses Flash mode it's not working. What's wrong?

My JWPlayer setup:

```
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    file: '/1.mp4',
    height: '100',
    width: '100%',
    bufferlength: 50,
    repeat: 'none',
    startparam: 'start',
    modes: [
        { 'type': 'html5' },
        { 'type': 'flash', src: '/mediaplayer/player.swf' }
    ],
    autostart: 'false'
});
```

Comment: Try "starttime" instead of just "start"

Comment: @EthanLongTail It didn't work and something strange happened, now in firefox player waits for the whole file to load and then starts playback.

Comment: Ah, that can be fixed with the following tool - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Comment: @EthanLongTail Thanks for your reply but I'm wondering why it's working in html5 mode but not in flash player?

Comment: Seeking working in html5 is due to the fact that html5 supports this out of the box and flash requires a pseudo streaming module installed.

Comment: Doesn't JWplyer 5.8 supports it?

Comment: Yep. http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw5/31144/http-pseudo-streaming

Comment: I checked my files with `QTIndexSwapper`, it says that MOOV is in proper place and processing is not needed. I still have the same problem with Flash version of JWPlayer, what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have the pseudo streaming module actually installed on your web server?

Comment: Can you have your host check? Usually things like this happens when the module is not installed properly.